# get all dialogs in page in AEM

Tags: extjs, aem

Is there any direct way to get dialog object of all components which are dragged on page.

For ex: when we load page and if there is any component like text, image are on page, I can get dialog. Please suggest?

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate what you are trying to do with these dialogs? What you have is a '/libs/wcm/core/content/components.TIMESTAMP.json' XHR request, where all components are listed together with their dialog path. Then you would have to parse your HTML to get the used components based on their css class though this can be a bit ambiguous as the css class only consists of the last part of the 'resourceType' e.g. "textimage"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Attach a listener which listens to the `editablesready` event fired by WCM. Get all the editables on the page using the `#getEditables()` method of `CQ.WCM` and then get the dialog of each editable if it is present.

Sample code below.

```
CQ.WCM.on('editablesready', function() {
    var editables = CQ.WCM.getEditables();

    for(var path in editables) {
        var editable = editables[path];
        try {
            console.log(editable.getEditDialog());
            //Do stuff
        } catch(e) { }
    }
});
```

Comment: That for your solution. But I am not able to get the values of textfields,pathfields present in any dialog like i am able to get in existing dialog Or is there any other way of getting values

Comment: Values will not be available on page load, rather they are requested for when the author opens any dialog using the `#loadContent()` method of the dialog. Behind the scenes, it makes an ajax request to the node to fetch all the properties and values and then populates the dialog accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. it helped in understanding the scenario.